# How to create STA threads in SmartThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using SmartThreadPool by Ami Bar 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx

Although it is mentioned there that STA threads can be spawned, but i couldn't find an example. I want to create all STA threads in my pool.

Answer (score 4):

That's a bad idea.  The lifetime of a threadpool thread is determined by the code it executes, preferably short and snappy.  This is *not* the rule for an STA thread, it must stay active and pump a message loop as long as the COM objects that were created on that thread are not finalized.  A requirement that's very incompatible with a TP thread.  Trying to do this anyway will just buy you never-ending misery with "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" exceptions as well as deadlock.  This is why a .NET tp thread is always MTA.

You must use a regular Thread.

Comment: We release COM objects using 'Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject' in the ThreadPool, and never had problems with RCW..

Comment: It has nothing to do with the release call, it is *creating* a COM object on such a thread that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, the [current version](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool#Feature29) does support STA threads:

```
STPStartInfo stpStartInfo = new STPStartInfo();
stpStartInfo.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
SmartThreadPool stp = new SmartThreadPool(stpStartInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed the source code and found out that SmartThreadPool doesn't support STA threads. The only way to create them is to modify the sources as follows:

1. Add *StartSTAThreads* property to the *STPStartInfo* class.
2. Add

   ```
   if (_stpStartInfo.StartSTAThreads) 
   {
       workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   }
   ```

to the *SmartThreadPool.StartThreads* method before *workerThread.Start()* call.